# Chrome inspect not allowing to add CSS property

Tags: html, css, cordova, google-chrome, webview

I have a cordova built application on android and using chrome://inspect/#devices I can inspect HTML elements and alter css properties.

I have 2 phones, when I run the application in Oneplus 2 I can inspect and add css property but when I run the same app in Moto G (2nd Gen android version 6.0), I can inspect the HTML DOM, edit existing css but I cannot add a new css property.

Comment: Same versions of Chrome?

Comment: Chrome version : Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Yes tested on same version